# windows game xna 4.0 VS2012 can't add class to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

Earlier today i installed XNA 4.0 on my computer.

I managed to port it from VS2010 to VS2012 by moving the folder in extensions\microsoft and update the manifest from 10.0 to 11.0

Additionally i did a "devenv.exe" /setup.

After that I was able to create projects for windows based on XNA 4.0 under projects.

But when i do create a project i get an error message saying "A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'projectname' 
object reference not set to an instance of an object."

At first i thought that was just a minor error, clicked OK and went on to the project.

But after the project was created, only maintaining the XNA library, I was not able to create any classes. I was limited to XML, bitmap, effects and sprite font. along with all the stuff in the graphics tab.

Hope anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: Those are the options within an XNA content project, so just to sanity-check here - you're trying to add items to a normal game/library project, right? (It hasn't just created a single content project for you, without the game/library project?)

Comment: Yea that is the case.